# How the method delete_if works in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Why after this block of code the output is: [9.5]? I mean .. why the delete_if method deletes even my 'a' from my array?

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 'a', 9.5]

x.delete_if{ |elem| elem.to_i <= 3}

p x
```

Comment: FYI: `x.delete_if { |elem| elem.kind_of?(Numeric) && elem <= 3 }` retains `'a'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not about `delete_if`, it's about `to_i`

```
'a'.to_i
 => 0
```

`to_i` gives you `0` in those cases in which it doesn't know how to make your object an integer